# BEM naming for wrappers for repeated blocks

Tags: bem

I am unsure of the best way to name my BEM blocks, where they require a wrapper.
For example, given the following markup:

```
<div class="products-list">

  <div class="product__item">
    <div class="product__item__title">Product 1</div>
    <img class="product__item__image" />
  </div>

  <div class="product__item">
    <div class="product__item__title">Product 2</div>
    <img class="product__item__image" />
  </div>

</div>
```

I feel that the top wrapper (products-list) is kind of lost.

It's obviously too deep to use something like:

```
products-list__product__item__image
```

So, how do we handle wrappers in BEM *where the child elements are also wrappers*?

Comment: An element `.product__item__title` is invalid. If you want to keep all in a single block `.product`, then you have to use a flat naming convention: `.product__item`, `.product__item-title`, `.product__item-image`. Because in the BEM tree, the elements `item`, `.item-title`, `.item-image` are all brothers (independently of their relation in the DOM tree).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With two blocks `.product-list` and `product-item`.

```
<div class="product-list">
  <div class="product-list__item product-item">
    <div class="product-item__title">Product 1</div>
    <img class="product-item__image" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-list__item product-item">
    <div class="product-item__title">Product 2</div>
    <img class="product-item__image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the elements `.product-list__item` share the node with blocks `.product-item`.

Or, if the CSS rules for your list can be reused in your design, you can rename `.product-list` to a more generic `.list`:

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="list__item product-item">
    <div class="product-item__title">Product 1</div>
    <img class="product-item__image" />
  </div>
  <div class="list__item product-item">
    <div class="product-item__title">Product 2</div>
    <img class="product-item__image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! I like it - kind of an overlap bridging the two.
Is this the 'official' way?

Comment: It is valid. An element and a block (or two blocks) on the same DOM node is called a "mix".